# Find file and grep text from file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to search files from the subfolder and grep row from the file. Text files have 3 rows, the expected result is grepping 2nd row. I hope the file name pass to Get-Content,
but it failed.

```
Get-ChildItem -Name -Recurse -File -Include *.txt* | (Get-Content $_)[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is almost fine, the parenthesis should be wrapping the whole expression and `$_` should not be there:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Name -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt* | Get-Content)[2]
```

You could add `-TotalCount 2` to `Get-Content` so it only reads the first 2 lines however if the files only have 3 lines it wouldn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I understand Get-ChildItem is not String.

```
$f = (Get-ChildItem -Name -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt*) -as [string[]]
$i = 1
foreach($j in $f) {
#Write-Host $i : $j
Write-Host (Get-Content $j)[2]
$i++
}
```